# Refresh my tkinter label and lets it overwrite it with different output content

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Submit button that prints the output on the tkinter widget label. Everytime I change the input and click the Submit  the output is displayed but not at the same place i.e. The previous content of the label is not overwritten.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("ImageValidation ")
root.geometry("600x600+100+100")

pathlist = [None, None]  # holds the two files selected
labels = []

def browse_button(index):

    global filename
    filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Choose your file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpeg"),("all files","*.*")))
    pathlist[index] = filename

heading = Label(root, text = "Select 2 images you want to Validate", 
font=("arial",15,"bold","underline"), fg="blue").pack()

label1 = Label(root, text = "Enter Image 1", font=("arial",10,"bold"), 
fg="black").place(x=10, y = 100)
label2 = Label(root, text = "Enter Image 2", font=("arial",10,"bold"), 
fg="black").place(x=10, y = 200)

button = Button(root,text="Choose an Sign1",width = 30,command= lambda: 
browse_button(0)).place(x=250, y= 100)
button =  Button(root,text="Choose an Sign2",width = 30,command= 
lambda: browse_button(1)).place(x=250, y= 200)

def display():

    ImageVerification(pathlist[0], pathlist[1])

    l1 = Label(root,text=Scriptoutput, width = 200 )
    l1.pack(side='bottom', padx=50, pady=50)
    #Scriptoutput is the output variable from the main code.

submit_button = Button(text="Submit", width=15,command = display)
submit_button.pack(side='bottom', padx=15, pady=15)

root.mainloop()
```

A 'refresh' button that would clear the Label of its content and lets you overwrite it.

Comment: What does `ImageVerification()` do?

Comment: It Check whether the 2 images match or not.  If it matches Displays 'Matched' in the 'Scriptoutput' variable, used in the label l1.   So when i choose 2 new Image file n hit submit    the Display msg does not overwrite the previous one rather displays it on other positions of the widget. @Miraj50

Comment: You have posted similar question before and I have answered it.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking your function `ImageVerification()` as a blackbox and assuming it is working.

The reason this is happening is because you create a new Label, whenever the Submit button is pressed. What you have to do is to create the *display Label* outside the function and *configure its text*, whenever the button is pressed. Something like this.

```
l1 = Label(root, text="", width=200)
l1.pack(side='bottom', padx=50, pady=50)

def display():
    ImageVerification(pathlist[0], pathlist[1])

    l1.configure(text=Scriptoutput)
    #Scriptoutput is the output variable from the main code.

submit_button = Button(text="Submit", width=15,command = display)
submit_button.pack(side='bottom', padx=15, pady=15)
```

Comment: Perfect!!     Thanks alot.

Comment: @RamandeepSingh You are welcome. Please consider accepting it if it helped you.